# random 502 bad gateway errors with Strapi endpoints - app deployed on Fly.io + postgres database on Supabase

Tags: postgresql, strapi, supabase, fly

I've managed deploying my Strapi app on Fly.io, connected to a PostgreSQL database on Supabase.

I've followed [this Strapi guide](https://forum.strapi.io/t/fly-io-deployment/22438), but it seems a little bit outdated so I made some custom edits on my setup.

It... sometimes work, but I regulary get `502 bad gateway` errors (after one minute).

It feels like the app was idle.  After a while, I start to get responses (a few seconds) and it works.  A few hours later, it does not response again.

## About my setup

The default port in Strapi is 1337.

But Fly.io [now charges](https://community.fly.io/t/announcement-shared-anycast-ipv4/9384) 2$/mo to use custom ports.
Since I'm a *hobby* user, I then need to use the "free" ports, which are 80 and 443.

### database.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST','localhost'),
      port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME','postgres'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      schema: env('DATABASE_SCHEMA', 'public'), // Not required
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL_SELF', false),
      },
    },
    debug: false,
  },
});
```

also tested with

```
  ssl: false
```

### fly.toml

```
[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 80
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

[[services.ports]]
  force_https = true
  handlers = ["http"]
  port = 80

[[services.ports]]
  handlers = ["tls", "http"]
  port = 443

[[services.tcp_checks]]
  grace_period = "1s"
  interval = "15s"
  restart_limit = 0
  timeout = "2s"

[env]
  PORT="80"
```

### dockerfile

```
# Expose the Strapi port
EXPOSE 80
```

It seems that some other users have this problem on Fly.io + Supabase.
Someone says [here](https://community.fly.io/t/getting-502-gateway-error-all-of-a-sudden-when-trying-to-access-endpoints-that-touches-postgres-db-hosted-in-supabase/9605)

> that would mean the connection gets closed before response headers
> are fully sent back from your app.

Can anyone help ?  Thanks !